# Is it still possible to extract likes and shares from Facebook widget buttons?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like

I'm writing an application that will crawl a website and display the social share count for each page. I've got Pinterest, GPlus, and Linkedin all working fine through normal API's or widget APIs. However the Facebook rate limit for my call of

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?fields=og_object{likes.limit(0).summary(true)},share&id=http://www.test.com
```

Is making my application horribly slow.

Is it still possible to extract Like and Share counts from the Like and Share facebook widget? I've seen some old examples but these seem to be out of date now.

Here is the iFrame URL for the like widget generation on BoredPanda.com

```
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/plugins/like.php?action=like&app_id=469101399768819&channel=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FnRK_i0jz87x.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Dfe49902d750bd8%26domain%3Dwww.boredpanda.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.boredpanda.com%252Ff2738b4b0ea9d58%26relation%3Dparent.parent&container_width=96&href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fboredpanda&layout=button_count&locale=en_US&sdk=joey&share=false&show_faces=false&width=140
```

Parts such as `nRK_i0jz87x.js` might be frequently changing to stop scraping I'm not sure.

Any advice or experience with this is very welcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, Social Plugins are like a black box, you can´t get anything from them - and scraping is not allowed anyway: https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php